# Python has stopped working a problem caused this program from working

Tags: python, kivy, syntax-error

I'm learning Kivy. when I continued learning the .kv file tutorial I made some code too but when I ran it, it came up a weird error.

ERROR PHOTO:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvxu5.png

here's my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder, builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyLayout(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            pass
class UiApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyLayout()
UiApp().run()
```

I tried An Idea but it didn't work too:
the idea is that I made a folder and put the .kv file in it I changed my code to this

CODE:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder, builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
Builder.load_file("/run/my.kv")
class MyLayout(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            pass
class UiApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyLayout()
UiApp().run()
```

BUT now another error came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    Builder.load_file("/run/my.kv")
 File "C:\Users\Cherry.VenkatHP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib
 \site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 304, in load_file
 with open(filename, 'r', encoding=encoding) as fd:
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/run/my.kv'
```

can anyone help with my problem/ERROR

Comment: I see your error says ```C:\Users\``` bla bla so it uses this kind of slash, while you use ```/run/my.kv``` the other kind of slash, I would try replacing ```/``` with ```\```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `MyLayout` class:

```
class MyLayout(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            pass
```

Defining the `__init__()` method in that way prevents the required `Widget` initialization. Change the definition to:

```
class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass
```